# My docker-compose is not working properly?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

So basically I am using docker-compose to run 3 services together. Those services include the UI of the application, a PostgreSQL DB and the API server of the application.

Currently I have tried running the docker-compose.yaml using docker-compose up command.Presently i am able to see the UI of the application but in the UI page itself there is an option to create a new folder.But unfortunately the option to create new folder in the UI page doesnt work.This obviously means that the api server is not working properly.

```
version: "3"

services:
  pg_db:
    image: postgres
    networks: 
      - wootzinternal
    ports:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=wootz
    volumes:
      - wootz-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  apiserver:
    image: wootz-backend
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks: 
      - wootzinternal
    depends_on:
      - pg_db
    ports:
      -  '8000:8000'
  ui:
    image: wootz-frontend
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/build
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - wootzinternal
    ports:
      - '80:3000'

volumes:
  wootz-db:

networks:
  wootzinternal:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile used for api server

```
FROM node:12.4.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

Dockerfile used for UI(client) of the application

```
FROM node:12.4.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm run build
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

config.json used while creating api image using dockerfile

```
{
"development": {
"username": "postgres",
"password": "password",
"database": "wootz",
"host": "pg_db",
"dialect": "postgres"
},
"test": {
"username": "postgres",
"password": "password",
"database": "wootz",
"host": "pg_db",
"dialect": "postgres"
},
"production": {
"username": "postgres",
"password": "password",
"database": "wootz",
"host": "pg_db",
"dialect": "postgres"
}
}
```

logs of running npm run migrate in the api server container

```
/usr/src/app # npm run migrate

> wootz-backend@1.0.0 migrate /usr/src/app
> sequelize db:migrate --config config/config.json


Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.4.0, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.8.7]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20190604071255-create-folders: migrating =======
== 20190604071255-create-folders: migrated (0.027s)

== 20190604072132-create-views: migrating =======
== 20190604072132-create-views: migrated (0.018s)
```

logs of the docker-compose

```
vignesh@master-node:~/cors new files$ sudo docker-compose logs
sudo: unable to resolve host master-node
Attaching to corsnewfiles_apiserver_1, corsnewfiles_ui_1, corsnewfiles_pg_db_1
apiserver_1  |
apiserver_1  | > wootz-backend@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
apiserver_1  | > nodemon index.js
apiserver_1  |
apiserver_1  | [nodemon] 1.19.1
apiserver_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
apiserver_1  | [nodemon] watching: *.*
apiserver_1  | [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
apiserver_1  | {
apiserver_1  |   username: 'postgres',
apiserver_1  |   password: 'password',
apiserver_1  |   database: 'wootz',
apiserver_1  |   host: 'pg_db',
apiserver_1  |   dialect: 'postgres'
apiserver_1  | }
apiserver_1  | folders
apiserver_1  | views
apiserver_1  | Listening on port 8000
pg_db_1      | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user                                                                                         "postgres".
pg_db_1      | This user must also own the server process.
pg_db_1      |
pg_db_1      | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8"                                                                                        .
pg_db_1      | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
pg_db_1      | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
pg_db_1      |
pg_db_1      | Data page checksums are disabled.
pg_db_1      |
pg_db_1      | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data                                                                                         ... ok
pg_db_1      | creating subdirectories ... ok
pg_db_1      | selecting default max_connections ... 100
pg_db_1      | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
pg_db_1      | selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
ui_1         | > wootz@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
pg_db_1      | creating configuration files ... ok
ui_1         | > node scripts/start.js
pg_db_1      | running bootstrap script ... ok
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
ui_1         | Starting the development server...
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
ui_1         | Compiled with warnings.
pg_db_1      | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A                                                                                        , or
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
ui_1         | ./src/registeredComponent/temporary/temporary.js
pg_db_1      | syncing data to disk ... ok
ui_1         |   Line 1:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | Success. You can now start the database server using:
ui_1         | ./src/registeredComponent/textFiled/textFiled.js
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         |   Line 1:  'Component' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
ui_1         |
ui_1         | ./src/components/Data/dragAndDrop/master.js
pg_db_1      |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
pg_db_1      |
pg_db_1      | waiting for server to start....2019-07-03 05:49:53.111 UTC [43] L                                                                                        OG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.128 UTC [44] LOG:  database system was shut d                                                                                        own at 2019-07-03 05:49:52 UTC
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.133 UTC [43] LOG:  database system is ready t                                                                                        o accept connections
pg_db_1      |  done
ui_1         |   Line 22:  'Link' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
pg_db_1      | server started
pg_db_1      | CREATE DATABASE
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         | ./src/components/Data/formListing/Formlisting.js
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         |   Line 49:  'mapStateToProps' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                          no-unused-vars
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-                                                                                        initdb.d/*
ui_1         | ./src/common/getFieldList.js
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         |   Line 54:   Expected to return a value at the end of arrow funct                                                                                        ion  array-callback-return
ui_1         |   Line 158:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow funct                                                                                        ion  array-callback-return
pg_db_1      | waiting for server to shut down...2019-07-03 05:49:53.497 UTC [43                                                                                        ] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
pg_db_1      | .2019-07-03 05:49:53.499 UTC [43] LOG:  aborting any active trans                                                                                        actions
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.501 UTC [43] LOG:  background worker "logical                                                                                         replication launcher" (PID 50) exited with exit code 1
ui_1         | ./src/common/common.js
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.508 UTC [45] LOG:  shutting down
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.519 UTC [43] LOG:  database system is shut do                                                                                        wn
ui_1         |   Line 551:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow funct                                                                                        ion  array-callback-return
pg_db_1      |  done
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      | server stopped
ui_1         | ./src/components/Data/formListing/FolderList.js
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         |   Line 5:  Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor
pg_db_1      | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
ui_1         |
pg_db_1      |
ui_1         | ./src/components/Data/launchScreen/launchScreen.js
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.611 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "                                                                                        0.0.0.0", port 5432
ui_1         |   Line 75:   'newfolder' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                     no-unused-vars
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.611 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "                                                                                        ::", port 5432
ui_1         |   Line 75:   'alert' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                         no-unused-vars
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.613 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/                                                                                        var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
ui_1         |   Line 75:   'alertMessage' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                  no-unused-vars
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.629 UTC [61] LOG:  database system was shut d                                                                                        own at 2019-07-03 05:49:53 UTC
ui_1         |   Line 161:  No duplicate props allowed                                                                                                                                                                         react/jsx-no-duplicate-pr                                                                                        ops
pg_db_1      | 2019-07-03 05:49:53.635 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to                                                                                         accept connections
ui_1         |   Line 167:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with mean                                                                                        ingful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
ui_1         |   Line 182:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with mean                                                                                        ingful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
ui_1         |   Line 191:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with mean                                                                                        ingful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
ui_1         |   Line 202:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with mean                                                                                        ingful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
ui_1         |
ui_1         | Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
ui_1         | To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
ui_1         |
```

I expect to be able to create a new folder in the UI page which would then indicate that the api server is working correctly.But unfortunately at present I am able to only see the UI page in the browser and unable to create a new folder.

Comment: what can you see when you type this `docker-compose logs` ?

Comment: hi I have updated my question  with the logs of docker-compose just now!!

Comment: Its failing to build `ui_1` due to linting

Comment: whats linting???

Comment: you have too many problems check the logs and fix them first, docker is not the problem here